# Can someone please solve this? (Basic HTML)

Tags: html

I am using this code to link an embedded .swf file to another page inside an iframe :

```
<div onmousedown="window.location.href='http://www.pagewhichopens.com'" height=26 width=100>
    <object height=26 width=100>
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.bcd.com/embeddedfile.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="http://www.bcd.com/embeddedfile.swf" height=26 width=100></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

But when I cick on the swf the another page opens inside that iframe only which I don't want, I want it to open in the whole browser... which can be done by inserting target="_parent", but where should I put it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `top.location` to set the location of the top frame or `parent.location` for the immediate parent. `window` refers to the current context (inside the frame).

Answer (score -1):

To open some link in a new tab use `target="_blank"` to achieve this

Comment: But where should target="_blank" be put?

Comment: It is JavaScript, not a link, so the `target` attribute isn't applicable here.